# Multiple tables operation causes dead lock

Tags: mysql, sql, django, transactions, deadlock

When I was doing performance tunning on an api backended by django. I found it was easy to raise an error like this: dead lock found...

Code causing deadlock(I've simplicified for clarity):

```py
@require_POST
def create_sop_task(request):
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            save_id = transaction.savepoint()
            
            db_tpl_obj = SopTemplate.objects.filter(id=template_id).values("type", "status").first()
         
            db_new_st = SopTask.objects.create(**req_args)
            for i, item in enumerate(message):
                SopMessage.objects.create(**kwargs)

            SopTemplate.objects.filter(id=template_id).update(version_time=version_time)
            SopTask.objects.filter(template_id=template_id).update(version_time=version_time)
            SopMessage.objects.filter(template_id=template_id).update(version_time=version_time)

            transaction.savepoint_commit(save_id)
            return JsonResponse({"code": 0, "msg": "success", "data": {"id": db_new_st.id}})
    except Exception as e:
        # ...
```

`Manipulating order in transaction:`

create SopTask

create SopMessage

update SopTemplate

update SopTask

update SopMessage

`If tweak the order like this, everything goes well:`

create SopTask

update SopTask

create SopMessage

update SopMessage

update SopTemplate

But I can not figure it why this will cause dead lock and what's the good way to avoid it. Someone could explain that? I'll appreciate a lot.

I am using MySQL 5.7 with isolution level: READ COMMITTED.

Comment: What does "create" mean?  Maybe `INSERT` one row into one table?  And get the auto_increment id so it can be used in the next table?  etc, etc.  Please provide SQL.

Comment: Yeah, exactly...

Comment: Is the "If tweak..." a long process?  The longer it is, the more chance there is for a deadlock.  That is, assuming it is _inside_ the transaction.